# How to customize an npm package in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, github, fork, package-managers

I am trying to customize mutliselect package to support tab events in vuejs but i cant seem to see any reflection. I wish to know how to make changes in a library in vue.

What i tried is that i went into the node_modules and just added the tab event on the multiselect library file but i cant seem to see anything work.

```
<span
  v-if="option && (option.$isLabel || option.$isDisabled)"
  :data-select="groupSelect && selectGroupLabelText"
  :data-deselect="groupSelect && deselectGroupLabelText"
  :class="groupHighlight(index, option)"
  @keydown.enter.tab=="select(option)"
  @mouseenter.self="groupSelect && pointerSet(index)"
  @mousedown.prevent="selectGroup(option)"
  class="multiselect__option">
    <slot name="option" :option="option" :search="search">
      <span>{{ getOptionLabel(option) }}</span>
    </slot>
</span>
```

The files i am editing:

[image]

Comment: please share what have you tried ?

Comment: I just went into the node_modules and added the tab event but no reflection for so ever. I even tried console logging on enter event which is the default function but didnt found any thing reflecting

Comment: == is not valid

Comment: changed but still not working

Comment: I think you're using the transpiled script instead of  that you're trying to modify

Comment: Not sure about that. I added screen of the files  i am editing.

Comment: how do you import it?

Comment: The whole idea of have third party modules installed by npm is that you don't modify them. You'll loose the modifications when deploying to a server and performing a fresh install. You can however fork the package repository, adjust the code, push the changes to your fork and maybe even perform a pull request to the original package. Also you can than use your fork instead of the original package.

Answer (score 3):

A vue project uses a package manager (typically `npm` or `yarn`). This means it loads the packages based on what's specified in `package.json` when it serves and/or builds. The package manager might use its internal cache to provide the actual code.

So far you have only modified the source files of the package, not the output. And it's the built output that gets used in your project, just as in your project, when you build, you're deploying the contents of the `/dist/` folder, not what you have in `src/`.

The simplest way to achieve what you want is:

- fork the package into your github account
- commit and push the changes (depending on package this might involve building the package - look for the package's `package.json`'s `"build"` script)
- (totally optional and typically more involved) if it's a useful change (a bugfix, etc...) consider PR-ing it in the original package. It might get merged. Most package authors are happy to accept useful additions, especially if they don't break existing functionality.
- now go to your project's `package.json` and replace the version with your fork, like this (assuming the package is `vue-multiselect` and the fork branch you want is `develop`. Don't forget to replace `your-username` with your actual github username. if you don't specify a branch it will load the one that's set as default in your fork - in github project settings):

```json
"vue-multiselect": "github:your-username/vue-multiselect#develop"
```

- run `npm i` to apply the change.

---

Important note: you don't need to create a pull-request and for it to be merged in order for this to work. In fact, if you do PR and it gets merged, that's the point where you can switch back to the original package, provided you point to a version containing the mods.

Additional note: it is possible to get local changes to the package apply in your project (to test they work properly) by running `npm run build` in the package folder, in `node_modules/`. But if you build the project on any other machine it won't contain the mods. Not until you point the package in `package.json` to a version/fork containing the mods.

As a rule of thumb, you should treat all your projects as if before any `serve` (or `build`) you have deleted `node_modules` and ran `npm i`.